# Removing literal character in regex

Tags: java, regex

I have the following string

`\Qpipe,name=office1\E`

And I am using a simplified regex library that doesn't support the `\Q` and `\E`.

I tried removing them

```
 s.replaceAll("\\Q", "").replaceAll("\\E", "")
```

However, I get the error `Caused by: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal/unsupported escape sequence near index 1
\E
 ^`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`\` is the special escape character in both Java string and regex engine. To pass a literal `\` to the regex engine you need to have `\\\\` in the Java string. So try:

```
s.replaceAll("\\\\Q", "").replaceAll("\\\\E", "")
```

Alternatively and a simpler way would be to use the `replace` method which takes string and not regex:

```
s.replace("\\Q", "").replace("\\E", "")
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the Pattern.quote() function to escape special characters in regex for example

```
s.replaceAll(Pattern.quote("\Q"), "")
```

Answer (score 1):

`replaceAll` takes a regular expression string.  Instead, just use `replace` which takes a literal string.  So `myRegexString.replace("\\Q", "").replace("\\E", "")`.

But that still leaves you with the problem of quoting special regex characters for your simplified regex library.

Answer (score 0):

[String.replaceAll()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) takes a regular expression as parameter, so you need to escape your backslash twice:

```
s.replaceAll("\\\Q", "").replaceAll("\\\\E", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the below. I used this because i was matching and replacing a text wrapped and the Q & E would stay in the pattern. This way it doesn't.

```
final int flags = Pattern.LITERAL;
regex = "My regex";
pattern = Pattern.compile( regex, flags );
```