# Why does this pattern not match? ([\\\\A\\\\W]its[\\\\W\\\\z])

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I'm trying to do a replace with this pattern, so I need to match this:

```
String pattern = "[\\\\A\\\\W]its[\\\\W\\\\z]";
```

The way I'm interpreting my pattern is: either a beginning of the string OR a non word character like a space or comma, then an "its", then a non word character OR the end of the string.

Why doesn't it match on this "its" inside this string?

```
its about time
```

The idea of what this is supposed to do it's supposed to detect incorrectly written words like "its" and fix them to "it's".

Also why do I need so many escape characters in order for the pattern to be accepted by the vm at all?

Comment: you don't need that many escape characters: \\A should do the trick. A non word character is \s and not \W

Comment: @Absurd-Mind that's what I initially thought, but I was getting a regex compile error or something like that, I found this trick in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5314018/removing-literal-character-in-regex

Comment: @ArturasM Don't bother manually escaping. Try [this](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\\A` and `\\z` are *boundary matches*. They cannot go inside character classes. If you use them properly, i.e. with two slashes instead of four, regex pattern compiler would throw an exception, because `\A` or `\z` cannot go inside `[]` blocks.

Use straight `|` syntax with non-capturing groups instead:

```
String pattern = "(?:\\A|\\W)its(?:\\W|\\z)";
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/ExwI4a)

Comment: Seems to work perfectly, now to finalize my understanding, non capturing groups mean, that you later can not get the matches using something like $1, $2, $3, right? Although I don't know how to use that extraction of a group in Java, only in Perl.

Comment: @ArturasM You are absolutely right on the non-capturing groups. You can get capturing groups through the [`Matcher`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) object. `$n` syntax works in replacement APIs, including `String`'s `replaceAll`.

Comment: So if I did "its about time".replaceAll(pattern, "$1") and had used the capturing groups instead of non-capturing before, I would get what was found in "\\A|\\W", right? Would be grateful if you could confirm that. The other question I still have would be why do we necessarily have to use the non-capturing groups here? Is it for performance reasons if we are not going to be using those "$1", "$2"...?

Comment: @ArturasM Your expression does not use capturing groups, so the only group available for replacement is `$0`, which represents the entire match. [Here](http://ideone.com/nmD1t9) is a demo with a capturing group (note the round parentheses around "its"). It is a good idea to use non-capturing groups by default, and using capturing ones only as needed. This way the expression is more maintainable, because the code relying on multiple capturing groups wouldn't break if you add a non-capturing one in the middle. Performance considerations are too small, and can be ignored.